# ASP .NET Web Pages giving 404 error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a website running on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008.

I have the website home page

```
www.mywebsite.com/Default.aspx
```

The home page is working fine. But if i browse to page with url like

```
www.mywebsite.com/directory/Default.aspx
```

This page doesn't work. It gives me HTTP 404 error on IE/Oops the links appears to be broken on Chrome. The directory does exists on the server and all the links were working properly till yesterday. I have no clue why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to check your IIS web site configuration.

Is "directory" a physical or virtual folder? Is it correctly mapped under your default web site?

Comment: If things were working before then just try restarting app-pool..

Comment: It is a physical folder. And I checked the mapping it is fine. And only the home page which is in the root of the folder works but every other page gives me 404 error.

Comment: @Scorpio - I restarted the application pool but no luck.

Comment: Check the ExtensionlessUrlHandler in the IIS handler mappings and try to compare it with the working site. u should also check the permissions on the default page and the other pages..

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback. The web pages started working. We had an error on another of our websites which was - 'There is a time and/or date difference between the client and server' (this server was not the one where the web pages were hosted). After setting the NET TIME on the other server it started working. Weird but it works now.